# nuxt.js npm run " dev DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated "

Tags: npm, vuejs2, nuxt.js, npm-scripts

So i received a nuxt project and i wanted to run it on my local host but at first it gave me an error about my npm version being old so i ran `npm install` and tried again but it gave me the following error:

```
 ERROR  (node:3316) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead


 WARN  Compiled with 1 warnings                                     friendly-errors 16:18:10


 WARN  in ./assets/scss/main.scss                                   friendly-errors 16:18:10

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):   friendly-errors 16:18:10
Warning

(343:5) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
                                                                    friendly-errors 16:18:10
 @ ./assets/scss/main.scss 4:14-224 14:3-18:5 15:22-232
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Comment: its a warning. And its impossible to tell what wrong with your project without full reproduction

Comment: thanks...yeah i've read that it's a warning but i didn't find anything else that seem to be the problem...do you have any suggestions?